# Get numerical values from a behavior pattern with Regex

Tags: python, regex, expression

I am trying to create a regex that can cover most of the possibilities of a text pattern. The format I'm trying to find is the numeric value of a listing that can come with different monetary values.

Inside the behavior that I can find is to have a result like the following:

```
$ 8
```

expected result: 8

```
$ 12.548
```

expected result: 12.548

```
$ -8
```

expected result: -8

```
$ -6.098
```

expected result: -6.098

```
$ -59
```

expected result: -59

```
$ 778
```

expected result: 778

```
$ 73
```

expected result: 73

**It is important to note that only one record will come at a time, but the result can come with any of the formats previously shown. Also within the pattern the $ sign will always come.**

I need to have a regular expression that can find all the numerical values, however the one that is complicating me the most is the pattern with the negative number.

The expression I have, brings me only the positive values:

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$|))
```

As information I use Python 3.7 and I use the re.findall function to search for those records

Any ideas how to incorporate the negative numbers? Would I have to do it with a conditional?

Comment: Can you try `^-?[\d]\d*(\.\d+)?$` `RegEx` because, I think this `RegEx` will accept all the desired `test-cases`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exiting regex for positive number is already good.  You can just modify it a bit to enhance it to support also negative numbers, as follows:

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3DybHS/1)

[Python run demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurJLWiRMFWQUlJiUtFwQKIDY30TE1ADF0wYaZnYAlmmFoCSXNzENvcmAuknqugKDOvRKMoVS8tMy8lMSdHo0hd1z4mRVvD3ipGD0hr2qvrKIAs0NT8/x8A)

If you want to match only the number without any other characters following it, you can use:

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QnAb3g/1)

### Details:

`-?`   to match `-` literally but make it optional by `?`

`\d+`  match the integer part of one or more digits

`(?:`  to make a non-capturing group for the optional fractional part

`\.\d+`  to match a decimal point followed by one or more decimal point digits

`)?`     end of the optional fractional part

`$`    this is the anchor to asserts the end of the line so that if any characters follows the number, if will not match the whole number.

Answer (score 2):

To match the literal `$`, you have to escape it: `\$`, else it will try to match the end of line.

To match an integer, you can use `\d` to match a digit, and ask to match one or more: `\d+`

Matching the fractional part is trickier: you want to match the point, and then some digits after it: `\.\d+`. You need to escape the `.`, else it will match any character.

But you also want to match this whole thing zero or one times, using `?`. An obvious way to do that would be `(\.\d+)?`, but that would be a *capturing* group, and you likely want to capture the entire number, not the fractional part alone. So you use a non-capturing group: `(?:\.\d+)?`

You also don't want to allow any other characters *after* the number, so you want to match the end-of-line, the `$`.

All together now:

```
\$ (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

To understand better how things work in it, I'd recommend a tool like https://regex101.com/.

Ah, yes, the optional minus; I bet you can cope with that without my help now.

Answer (score 1):

To match all the example that you provided, you can try this instead:

```
 [-\d]
```

match "any digits that come with or without the - sign in front of it and ignore everything else.

Comment: Don't forget the decimal point: `[-\d.]+`

Comment: The downside of this pattern is that it will also match a `-` (or `.`) on its own, which is probably not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I want to adjust my previous answer which is very short when I consider only the example syntax that op wants to match. In the case that op wants to watch a specific number that follows one or more symbol $ and ignore any "." and "," in-between, it is a little more complicated. OP is very close to the right answer (in term of searching google) when he uses (?=$) for looking ahead which refer to the condition that "A number must follow by the symbol $", not mentioning the "|" in his full solution:

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$|))
```

which then, fortunately, help him to escape the wrong condition and again match every group of number with "." in between. Although this is not the answer that we wanted.

Since we want our condition to start with "$" to distinguish it from any random number that is not a part of the money we care about, we start with:

```
(?<=\$)
```

the full syntax:

```
(?<=\$)(-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)
```

for a pattern that only contains "." and :

```
(?<=\$)(-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|(-?[0-9]+\,[0-9]+)
```

for a pattern that contains both "." and "," but not "." and "," between a number, for example with the following string:

```
" $-99.000 $10.0000 $$$999,000 $-99,000ppjujj okeer134124- "
```

the code should give you:

```
[('-99.000', ''), ('10.0000', ''), ('', '999,000'), ('', '-99,000')]
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: The `$` in `(?=$|))` is not the literal symbol `$` itself.  Regex meta-character `$`
matches the end of a string without consuming any characters. If multiline mode is used, this will also match immediately before a newline character.  I also noticed OP's previous regex has this lookahead at the end.  But it seems unnecessary in this use case.  That's why I removed this in my answer but added another alternative solution with `$` at the end so that the numbers are not followed by any other characters in the line.

Comment: thanks for the adjustment, I didn't notice this difference.